# How to serialize a C# object to json so it looks like "["starts-with", "$key", "user/john/"]"?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to create a viewmodel in C# that can be serialized into a json document required by amazon S3. Documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy).  One of the properties looks like this,

```
 ["starts-with", "$key", "user/john/"]
```

What would the C# object look like so when it's serialized it would come out like this?
Rest of document looks like this.

```
    { "expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",

  "conditions": [

    {"acl": "public-read" },

    {"bucket": "johnsmith" },

    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/john/"],

  ]

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a string array

```
string[] data = new string[] { "starts-with", "$key", "user/john/" };
```

The object structure for the second part would be something like

```
public class S3Expiration {
    DateTime expiration { get; set; }
    object[] conditions { get; set; }
}
```

and to populate it you would write something like

```
var expiration = new S3Expiration {
    expiration = DateTime.Now,
    conditions = new object[] {
        new { acl = "public-read" },
        new { bucket = "johnsmith" },
        new string[] { "starts-with", "$key", "user/john/" }
    }
};
```